# dir Z: works in cmd but fails in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

dir Z: works in cmd but fails in PowerShell.

I need this for a script.

What am I doing wrong?

```
PowerCLI C:\> Get-ChildItem Z:
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem Z:
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Z:String) [Get-ChildItem],    DriveNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :  DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: PowerCLI? Are you trying to access a VM?

Comment: *A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist.* -> that seems pretty self explanatory. I'm going to guess that you "Ran as administrator" or "ran as another user" or ran as scheduled task or etc. and cannot access a mapped drive from your original user's context in this context.

Comment: Can you see it with Get-PSDrive

Comment: Thanks!  That was it!  I was running PowerCLI (aka PowerShell with VMware snapins) as administrator.  Once I opened a PowerCLI session as me, dir Z: worked.   Thanks again!